# JQuery and showing / hiding content

Tags: jquery

Why does this not work? I have looked for tutorials online but they only show how to show/hide with a button. I want to toggle the height of an element.

```
$('.oldestinititives').mousedown(function() {
    $(this).animate({"height": 450}, "slow");
    $(this).addClass("pop");
});
$('.pop').mousedown(function() {
    $(this).animate({"height": 250}, "slow");
    $(this).removeClass("pop");
});
```

in the CSS, the block is 250px by default. Clicking the element does reveal the content, but clicking it again does not hide it. Using firebug I can see that the class 'pop' is added but it doesn't seem to target it. What is going on?

thanks,
Evan

Comment: In the Firebug error console, are you getting any errors?

Comment: Please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo.

Comment: Here is the JSfiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WF6R4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this  (working example
http://jsfiddle.net/saelfaer/CyD2g/)

```
$('.oldestinititives').live("click", function() {
    if($(this).is('.pop'))
    {
        $(this).animate({"height": 250}, "slow", function(){
            $(this).toggleClass("pop");
        }); 
    }
    else
    {      
        $(this).animate({"height": 450}, "slow", function(){
            $(this).toggleClass("pop");
        }); 
    }
});
```

i took the liberty to merge your two event handlers in one, as they could have been merged, depending on what you actually do inside the function you could make it even shorter without the big if-else structure...

**the idea here is that you use `.live("click", function(){});` this will bind the event to any item that ever will be a valid candidate for your selector. even when at the time of executing the code the element does not have the right class name or ID yet.**

Comment: Very cool! Still learning JQuery so this code is extremely helpful, thank you very much!

Comment: you can see that apart from the actual height variable both the if and else clause are the same, so you could basically drop that in a separate variable and only use the animation code once... but that highly depends on what else you do in the callback after the animation of course.  another thing i did was move the class toggle to the callback function (now it happens AFTER the animation is complete) in your code it was on the same line, so it would happen immediately.

Answer (score 1):

As you are adding the class at runtime, are you using jquery `live()` to bind events? If not please use it:

```
http://api.jquery.com/live/
```

Comment: Ah right that seems to work. But now, the box just shortens right after the click, like it takes both at once.... hmm

Answer (score 0):

At the time you are hooking the mousedown event to the elements with the `pop` class, there are no elements matching this selector. You have to bind the event as you add the class for this to work. Or even better: use [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) or [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) to bind the events

Comment: I've added the live(), but now it takes both commands at once, if that makes any sense. Please see here: http://jsfiddle.net/WF6R4/

Comment: Yes, that makes sense as you never remove the eventhandler from the `oldestinititives`-elements. @Sander has a good solution. If you still want to handlers you can bind them both with delegate/live and toggle the selector class ie pop/unpop